# How to use a MAUI Picker with a view model based on an SQLite database?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, mvvm, maui

My MAUI .Net application to handle sport events needs to work with several databases, one with the different squads and one with the participants. I want to use a picker so I can select the squad of a participant when creating/editing its details, but I end up with an empty picker when I open a participant to see its details.
When debugging, I can see the SelectedSquad is set properly when I save/load a participant, but it doesn't appear in the picker despite the SelectedItem binding.

My participant View Model (contains the standard informations about the participant and the ones extracted from the Squad database):

```cs
using MatchTracker.Pages;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;

namespace MatchTracker.Models.ViewModels
{
    public partial class ParticipantDetailsVM : BaseViewModel, IQueryAttributable
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        Participant currentParticipant;

        [ObservableProperty]
        Squad selectedSquad;

        public ObservableCollection<Squad> SquadsList { get; }

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string saveButtonText;

        public ParticipantDetailsVM()
        {
            Title = "Participant Details";
            SquadsList = new ObservableCollection<Squad>();
        }

        public async void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(query["id"].ToString()), out int Id))
                if (Id == 0)
                {
                    SaveButtonText = "Add Participant";
                    CurrentParticipant = new Participant { Id = 0 };
                }
                else
                {
                    SaveButtonText = "Update participant";
                    CurrentParticipant = await App._ParticipantsDb.GetAsync(Id);
                }
        }

        async Task LoadSquads()
        {
            try
            {
                SquadsList.Clear();

                var all = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
                foreach (var item in all)
                {
                    SquadsList.Add(item);
                }
            
                SelectedSquad = await App._SquadsDb.GetAsync(CurrentParticipant.SquadId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                RefreshNeeded = false;
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task SaveParticipant()
        {
            try
            {
                CurrentParticipant.SquadId = SelectedSquad.Id;
                await App._ParticipantsDb.AddAsync(CurrentParticipant);
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(ParticipantsListView));

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        public async void OnAppearing()
        {
            await LoadSquads();
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML file for my participant View:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MatchTracker.Pages.ParticipantDetailsView"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MatchTracker.Models.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:ParticipantDetailsVM"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <TableView Intent="Data">
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection Title="Basic Information">
                    <EntryCell x:Name="ParticipantNameField" Label="Name" Text="{Binding CurrentParticipant.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
        <Picker x:Name="ParticipantSquadPicker" Title="Squad" ItemsSource="{Binding SquadsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSquad, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Label x:Name="Debug" Text="{Binding CurrentParticipant.SquadId}"/>
        <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Text="{Binding SaveButtonText}" Command="{Binding SaveParticipantCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The .cs file linked to the previous XAML file:

```cs
using MatchTracker.Models.ViewModels;

namespace MatchTracker.Pages;

public partial class ParticipantDetailsView : ContentPage
{
    public ParticipantDetailsView(ParticipantDetailsVM vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ((ParticipantDetailsVM)BindingContext)?.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote [an example](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-76850111-MauiPicker) how to use the built-in Dependency Injection framework, navigation parameters and view initialization on appearing

Comment: You should consider removing all the fluff from your text that is not helping to answer. We do not care WHAT you develop, it is simply not relevant at all. Also, consider occasionally debugging. "I tried several different implementations but I always end up with no data in the picker" - that can be checked in a breakpoint. is this a MAUI presentation problem, or are you not getting the data? Depending what it is - the question can eliminate the other part of the equation (data problem? We do not care about MAUI, presentation problem - same about the whole database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks all for your answers, I finally found the solutions to both my problems :

- For the first issue, the picker not showing any data, as @Julian noticed the issue was with auto-generated properties, my properties where flagged as `[ObservableProperty]` but I was using the backing fields (`selectedSquad`) instead of the properties themselves (`SelectedSquad`), changing the lowercase to an uppercase letter solved this.
- The second issue, not being able to load a picker with preselected data, got solved this way :
  In my ViewModel, instead of

```cs
var all = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
foreach (var item in all)
{
    SquadsList.Add(item);
}
SelectedSquad = await App._SquadsDb.GetAsync(CurrentParticipant.SquadId);
```

I had to use

```cs
var all = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
foreach (var item in all)
{
    SquadsList.Add(item);
    if (item.Id == CurrentParticipant.SquadId) SelectedSquad = item;
}
```

Turns out even if the item list and selected item are from the same databases, the application doesn't consider the item to be part of the list.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Solution

Change this:

```cs
if (participant.SquadId != 0) squad = await App._SquadsDb.GetAsync(participant.SquadId);
squads = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
```

into this:

```cs
if (participant.SquadId != 0) Squad = await App._SquadsDb.GetAsync(participant.SquadId);
Squads = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
```

Notice the difference in the assignment of the [auto-generated properties](https://blog.ewers-peters.de/introduction-to-mvvm-source-generators-for-dotnet). Your UI doesn't get updated, because you assign values to the *backing fields* instead of the *properties*. Only when you set the value to the property, the auto-generated setter method of the observable property will invoke the `PropertyChanged` event, this doesn't happen when you manipulate the value of the backing field directly.

Since you're using an `async void` initializer, those backing fields only get set ***after*** the constructor finished execution, which means that the binding expressions aren't evaluated anymore after that. This happens because constructors always run synchronously, so your asynchronous method is still executing while the constructor already finished and changes the values of the backing fields although the binding expression was already executed. Thus, the Picker cannot know anything about those changed values for `Squad` and `Squads` without being notified about those changes.

## Improved Solution

Instead of using an `async void` initializer method, you should create a `Task` that you can `await`:

```cs
// leave constructor empty or remove it altogether
public ParticipantViewModel() { } 

// caller should await initializer
public async Task InitAsync(Participant participant)
{
    Name = participant.Name;
    if (participant.SquadId != 0) Squad = await App._SquadsDb.GetAsync(participant.SquadId);
    Squads = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
}
```

and then call it like this (e.g. in the `protected override async void OnAppearing()` method):

```cs
ParticipantVM = new ParticipantViewModel();
BindingContext = ParticipantVM;
await ParticipantVM.InitAsync(Participant);
```

Comment: Thanks @Julian for the great answer ! Helped a lot understanding what I did wrong with asynchronous code. However I still have an issue, when I load an already existing participant, the SelectedItem of the picker doesn't seem to be working, I always end up having an empty picker, even if when looking directly into the database file I can confirm SquadId isn't null. Any idea what's wrong on this point, still a matter of asynchronous code ?

Comment: Did you make sure to use `Squad` and `Squads` instead of `squad` and `squads` in the `InitAsync()` method? Can you add more information about the `Squad` class and debugging details about this directly to the question if it still doesn't work? Did you step through the debugger to see what values `Squads` and `Squad` have?

Comment: My project evolved a bit, I got a deeper explaination about all the auto-generated properties and ended up making a cleanier implementation which fixes my first issue, but I still can't show the SelectedItem when I load my picker, even if breakpoint shows me the Squad binded to the SelectedItem property isn't null.

Comment: You should update the question to reflect the current state of the code and the problem. Please try to add sufficient information for others to attempt to reproduce the issue and understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you going to use `ObservableProperty` that takes your field and make it into a property you need to use that property, ie use it as a property with a Capital S when assigning your field squad.

So your ViewModel should look like this to bind properyly

```cs
public partial class ParticipantViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ParticipantViewModel(Participant participant)
    {
        Name = participant.Name;
        InitAsync(participant);
    }
    private async Task InitAsync(Participant participant)
    {
        if (participant.SquadId != 0) Squad = await App._SquadsDb.GetAsync(participant.SquadId);
        Squads = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Squad squad;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<Squad> squads;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the following code of class `ParticipantViewModel.cs`:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<Squad> squads;
```

To

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Squad> squads;
```

Besides, we also use variables `Squads` that begin with an uppercase letter not `squads`.

```
public partial class ParticipantViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ParticipantViewModel(Participant participant) {
        name = participant.Name;
        InitAsync(participant);
    }
    private async void InitAsync(Participant participant)
    {  
        // use `Squads ` not `squads`
        if (participant.SquadId != 0) Squad = await App._SquadsDb.GetAsync(participant.SquadId);

        // here please cast the returned type to type ObservableCollection<T>
        Squads = await App._SquadsDb.GetAllAsync();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Squad squad;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Squad> squads;
}
```

For more information, check document [ObservableObject.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).